# How to add ONE column to ALL tables in postgresql schema

Tags: postgresql

question is pretty simple, but can't seem to find a concrete answer anywhere.

I need to update all tables inside my postgresql schema to include a timestamp column with default NOW(). I'm wondering how I can do this via a query instead of having to go to each individual table. There are several hundred tables in the schema and they all just need to have the one column added with the default value.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easy way with psql, run a query to generate the commands, save and run the results

```
-- Turn off headers:
\t
-- Use SQL to build SQL:
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE public.' || table_name || ' add fecha timestamp not null default now();'
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE' AND table_schema='public';

-- If the output looks good, write it to a file and run it:
\g out.tmp
\i out.tmp

-- or if you don't want the temporal file, use gexec to run it:
\gexec
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved my issue completely. I've spent majority of my time in SQL or MySQL DBs. You have saved me a TON of time. Much appreciated Frank!